# What is the midpoint of a half disk's diameter called? Can't find the answer anywhere else.

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is Point O called the center of the half disk (informally, semicircle)?  It's not the centroid since it's not at the center of mass.  I'm not sure if it should be called the center if it lies on an edge of the shape and it's only the center of the full disk.  I've never seen an official term for it for just a half disk.  Does anyone have an answer for this?

[image]

Comment: It is the "centre of the circle" and the "centre of the full disk" and the "midpoint of the straight edge of the half disk".  Any of these seems clear about what and where it is